# Find div based on child hidden input value and change CSS class on the div

Tags: jquery, css

I have divs (class 'case') that are generated in a PHP while loop.  Each div contains a hidden input field (name 'case_id) with a value of the case id in the MySQL DB.

```
<div class="viewport">
   <ul class="overview">
      <?php
        while ( $row_my_patients = mysql_fetch_assoc( $result_my_patients ) ) {

           echo "<li><div class='case'><img src='images/case_icons/" . $row_my_patients['patient_icon'] . "'  width='44' height='45' /><input name='case_id' type='hidden' value='". $row_my_patients['case_pk'] . "' /></div></li>";

        }
      ?>
   </ul>
</div>
```

Now, I want to find the div with class 'case' that contains a hidden input with value matching `$('#active_case').val();` then `addClass('active')` to that div.

How can I do this?

Comment: Why don't you just give them `#id`'s so that they're easier to find?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
//run through each div with class case
$('.case').each(function(i,elem){ 
  //compare the input field of each div to the value 'active_case'
  if($(elem).children('input').val() === $('#active_case').val()) { 
    //add class to current element (div) if child input === 'active case'
    $(elem).addClass('active');
  }
});
```

Comment: Tried that and not working..also tried $('.case').each(function(i,elem){ 
$(elem).addClass('active');
});

Comment: @PeterBrowne Have you thrown a debugger in your code to make sure you're running through at the right time?

Answer (score 2):

You can try this :

```
$('.case').addClass(function(){
    if($(this).children('input').val() == $('#active_case').val()) return 'active';
})
```

If it match the condition, it add class, else it just ignore it.

Answer (score 2):

You can do something like:

```
var val = $.trim($('#active_case').val());

$('.case').filter(function(idx, el){
    return val == $.trim($(this).find(':hidden').val())
}).addClass('active');
```

Demo: [Fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/arunpjohny/Jdk3q/)

Comment: None of these suggestions seem to work...  alert ($('#active_case').val()); shows the id ok and substituting the image in the div with $row_my_patients['case_pk']  shows the correct ids in the divs...

Answer (score 2):

**Try this**

```
$('input[name="case_id"]').each(function(){
    if($(this).val() == $('#active_case').val()){
        $(this).parent('div').addClass('active');
    }
});
```

**DEMO** http://jsfiddle.net/yeyene/trBN4/

Comment: Hi all...my bad.  They all work just fine.  MY problem was in the css useing .case:active instead of .case.active :-<  Thanks for all you help...I gave the answer to the first with a solution and others a vote.